# Proving various properties of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are metrics on $M$. Prove that the following are also metrics:

(a) $p = p_1 + p_2$

define $p_1(x,y) = |x-y|$ define $p_2(a,b) = |a-b|. p = p_1+p_2 = |x-y|+|a-b|$. But I don't know how to bring that together.

(b) $p = \max{(p_1,p_2})$

suppose $p_1 = \sup(x,y), p_2=\sup(a,b).$
 then $p=\sup(\sup(x,y),\sup(a,b))$

..which means that it is then a metric?

Prove that $p(x,y) = |1/x-1/y|$ is a metric on $(0,+\infty)$

here, we're claiming that $p(x,y)=p(1/x,1/y)$

But I'm not sure what theorem I can use to my advantage for this equation.

Comment: Please don't just post a list of problems here for us to do. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? What problems are you having with verifying the conditions for a metric?

Comment: adding my work, sorry about that!

Comment: Are you choosing to define $p1$ and $p2$ these ways or are you supposed to show this for arbitrary metrics $p1$ and $p2$ and are choosing to represent them in such ways?

Comment: I chose to define $p1$ and $p2$ in this way. I don't know how to do this otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary metrics $p_1$ and $p_2$ on the space $X$ you don't want to define $p_1$ and $p_2$. Consider points $x,y \in X$. Then you want to show $p(x,y) = p_1(x,y) + p_2(x,y)$ is also a metric. You want to show that the metric $p$ fulfills the definition of a metric space. If you are not familiar with the definition take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). Then, similarly for b you will have to show the same thing for **arbitrary** metrics, do not define them.

Comment: yes, I am dealing with it in general terms. i understand now why I can't use arbitrary definitions.

Comment: General and arbitrary here are the same (mathematical jargon). You want a **general** metric, or **arbitrarily chosen** metric (meaning it could be any metric). What you have provided in your question is a **specific** metric, namely $p(x,y) = abs(x-y)$.